# How to navigate to a URL by calling on a method? Java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am having issues implementing a way to navigate a URL where the user simply needs to try and change a variable.

I am unable to use the navigate().to() method as it expects a string but want to know if there is a way around this to be able to navigate to a url?

Code below:

steps page - steps.java

```
    @Given("^I navigate to test website$")
    public void i_navigate_to_test_website() throws Throwable {
        driver.navigate().to(test.setEnvironment("testEnvironment"));
    }
```

class page - test.java

```
public void setEnvironment(String platform) {

    if(platform.equalsIgnoreCase("testEnvironment"))
    {
    env= Env1;
    }

    EnvUsed.add(env);
}

public static String Env1 = "http://www.test1.com";
public static String Env2 = "http://www.test2.com";
public static String Env3 = "http://www.test3.com";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below answer might help you to navigate url with a variable ( parametric ).

**steps page - steps.java**

```
 @And("^I navigate to test website$")
    public void navigateTestEnv(DataTable testEnv) {
        List<List<String>> data = testEnv.raw();
        classpage.navigateTestEnv(data.get(1).get(1));
    }
```

**class page - test.java**

```
public ProductPage navigateTestEnv(String testEnv) {
    driver.navigate().to(testEnv);
}
```

Cucumber Feature page - test.feature

```
And I navigate to test website
    | Fields | Values |
    | testEnv | http://www.test1.com |
```